# Multiple wordpress category IF with OR conditional not working

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I wanted to select one of 3 or more conditional statement, but I can't get it work as intended. It showing "Game title: 1". 
Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?php echo "<strong>Game Title: </strong>";
    if( $info = get_field('pcgame_name') || get_field('psppublisher') || get_field('ps3game_name') ) { ?>
        <?php echo $info;?>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: you have 3 conditions. which one them returning `true`? you need to provide more details about your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single "=" is an assignment i.e making $info = 1 (because one or more of the functions is returning True/1). You use "==" to check for equality so you probably want:

```
<?php echo "<strong>Game Title: </strong>";
if( $info == get_field('pcgame_name') || $info == get_field('psppublisher') || $info == get_field('ps3game_name') ) { ?>
    <?php echo $info;?>
<?php } ?>
```

Edit:  If you are not trying to compare a value with $info but instead trying to echo the value of the first non-empty ACF field then try this:

```
<?php echo "<strong>Game Title: </strong>";
   $info =  get_field('pcgame_name');
   if (empty($info)) $info = get_field('psppublisher');
   if (empty($info)) $info = get_field('ps3game_name');
   echo $info;
?>
```

Comment: sorry, it's not working :( ,it not showing the field value. Output: "Game Title: "